# Splash screen never fully loading before being closed

Tags: c#, winforms, splash-screen

I am currently adding a splash screen to my winform. My splash screen is just another form, where,

```
this.Text = "";
this.ControlBox = False;
```

All that is in the form is a PictureBox with a BackgroundImage and

```
this.BackgroundImageLayout = BackgroundImageLayout.Center
```

and a ProgressBar that increments the value until the initialization of my MainForm is complete.

I use Show rather than ShowDialog to open the Splash. Well, the ProgressBar works perfectly as it should, but the BackgroundImage in the PictureBox never seems to load. All I see is a white background with a ProgressBar.

I use SplashScreen.Show() in the same method that increments the ProgressBar, and this method is called in a method that is called from the constructor of the MainForm.

I have tried using SplashScreen.Show in a separate thread but that caused the same problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I'm willing to provide any more information if needed.

**Solved:**

When starting it in its own thread ShowDialog must be used because Show will close the form when the thread ends, but with ShowDialog, the thread will stay running until the form is closed. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are blocking the message queue, but without seeing more code I can't be sure.

You may want to have a look at this splash screen project.  I have used it before.  Works great.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5454/A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C

Among other things, that project runs the splash screen on a separate thread to keep it responsive and prevent message queue blocking.

Comment: This sounds like it. You will need to spawn a new thread that either does the loading in the background or processes the message queue if the loading takes place in the foreground.

Comment: I actually have tried using Show() in a separate thread and it still didn't work. When does a backgroundimage get drawn? In InitializeComponent()?

Comment: It's been a while since I did WinForms, but the image is probably drawn in response to a windows message captured by the control saying it needs to redraw itself.  If you're blocking the message queue, the control will not get that message.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your splash screen is being shown on the main thread, which immediately then goes on to do the other work of initializing your application and never has a chance to draw the splash screen.

You'll need to run your splash screen on its own thread to allow for it to draw cleanly.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446493.aspx